# JavaScript: calculate the difference between two objects in an array by key

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array of two objects:

```
const array = [{obj1: {price: 10, quantity: 10}, {obj2: {price: 20, quantity: 10}}}]
```

How do I calculate the difference between these two objects by each key, so as result I got:

```
{price: -10, quantity: 0}
```

I've tried to do this using reduce function, but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: input is invalid. also why is it an array if there is only 1 object inside, also is it only 2 objects 2 take difference

Comment: You misplaced a `}` it should be `[{obj1: {price: 10, quantity: 10}}, {obj2: {price: 20, quantity: 10}}]`

Comment: also why need a loop if it is difference you know it is 2 elements

Comment: @cmgchess, OP might want to generate a result object with N keys (where N is the number of keys in the actual object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is to produce an object with N number of keys (where N is the number of keys in the actual object), this code would work.

```js
const array = [{obj1: {price: 10, quantity: 10}}, {obj2: {price: 20, quantity: 10}}];

const [obj1, obj2] = array.map((item) => Object.values(item)[0]);

const difference = Object.keys(obj1).reduce((result, key) => {
  if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    result[key] = obj1[key] - obj2[key];
  }
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(difference);
```

The output will be

```
{price: -10, quantity: 0}
```